# Google Custom Search. Direct answer

Tags: google-custom-search

Is it possible to get a direct answer from google custom search ?
If you run "who is the president of France" on google browser you will have the card of F.Hollande, above all the links.
If i run this key in google custom search i get just an array of results, but nothing as a clear answer.
Is there some google api for that ? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

As far I know, that feature is not available in CSE.

> Your custom search engine doesn’t include Google Web Search features
>   such as Oneboxes, real-time results, universal search, social feaures,
>   or personalized results.

Custom Search Help: "[**Custom Search vs Google.com**](https://support.google.com/customsearch/answer/70392?hl=en)"

Answer (score 0):

At SerpApi, we don't support yet direct answer boxes from Google knowledge graph. We do support the actual knowledge graph.

For example:

```
$ curl https://serpapi.com/search.json?q=who+is+the+president+of+France
...
  "knowledge_graph": {
    "title": "Emmanuel Macron",
    "image": "data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAIAAAP///////yH5BAEKAAEALAAAAAABAAEAAAICTAEAOw==",
    "description": "The current President of France is Emmanuel Macron, who succeeded François Hollande on 14 May 2017.",
...
```

You can find our API documentation here: https://serpapi.com/knowledge-graph